# Exchange Online - how to manage no-longer synchronised account?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

So we've got a setup of on-prem AD and EX Online. They are synchronised by aad connect and we've expanded the schema in AD, so we have the attribute to hide users from GAL.

Now, we've parted with a few users recently. What we want to do is to convert their mailbox to Shared mailbox, unassign the license and hide it from GAL. The AD Account has been moved to not-synced OU. The mailbox has been deleted automatically, but we've restored it. Now we can't change its -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled parameter, as it tells me, it's still managed by on-prem AD. How come? Doesn't matter, if I've forced removal of O365 account from powershell or not.

Comment: Where did you restore the user? Exchange Online or Office 365 portal? Did you get any error?
You could use Soft Match to sync the account from O365 to local AD.
How to use SMTP matching to match on-premises user accounts to Office 365 user accounts for directory synchronization
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2641663

Comment: We've only restored the mailbox, so Exchange Online. No errors with this.

Comment: Now you should check if the account is existing in 365 portal, if yes, you could use SMTP match to sync this acocunt again as mentioned.